# Z-Index not applying in Wordpress with Sticky Header

Tags: css, wordpress, z-index

I have a problem that a z-index property is not applying.
Is there a concrete dependency to other properties?

It looks right now like that, the Avada Theme sticky header is above everything:
[image]

The z-index of the header menu is "only" 10011:
[image]

Even if I set a style on ".fdm-ordering-sidescreen" with z-index to 200000, it is not above the menu.
WHY is that? Shouldn't it become on top?

shorturl.at/gjvS3

-> Click once on "add to cart" for a menu item, than click on the shopping cart icon and scroll!

Comment: The stacking context depends on the HTML structure as well. So simply setting higher `z-index` might not always work.

Comment: Is there a way to override that behaviour? Can you see from the link where the exact problem may lay?

Comment: Please read through this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context You would get an idea on it.

Comment: I will write an answer based on the article.

Comment: @m4n0: Thank you very much, highly appreciate it. IF you could give me the reason based on the html structure on the linked page, that would be very welcomed. So oder so... I'd look to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to unset the z-index value of `.fusion-fullwidth .fusion-row` to [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context): [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset)

[image]

Because now even when you set `.fdm-ordering-sidescreen` to 200000, it is calculated as 10.200000 courtesy of the `z-index` set on one of its parent `.fusion-fullwidth .fusion-row`.

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! If I do: `.fusion-fullwidth .fusion-row {z-index: 10011;}` than the sticky header is not above the content anymore when scrolling down. So the header needs to have a HIGHER z-index value than the content, otherwise it is not "sticky". Can we still fix it, so that even with a lower z-index value on `.fusion-fullwidth .fusion-row` that the sidecart still gets above the header???

Comment: Normally, when I work with the mini cart, they always are part of the header and not the content. This looks a different scenario. So you can simply try unsetting the `z-index` on it. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Unsetting the z-index of `.fusion-fullwidth .fusion-row` and giving `.fdm-ordering-sidescreen` a z-index greater than the sticky header.